# haven't heard back from the HR Team for my onboarding process

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment, human-resources, onboarding

So I already got an offer from them, signed it digitally then sent it back. After that I sent a resignation letter to my current job (First job btw). Went through pre-employment medical exam and then the company nurse gave me an update that I was fit to work based on the result. Provided all of my information for background checks, then the HR Team sent me an invite for the induction which was scheduled on April 26, 2021 then one of the HR coordinators called me an hour after the induction invitation that I should overlook it and they will send me a new invitation because they mistook my start date on April 26, 2021 instead of May 03, 2021. Ever since today (April 29, 2021) I haven't received any new invitation, I already texted the HR coordinator that called me still no response. So the whole process took about 1 month.

I'm feeling anxious because they might withdrawn my job offer anytime although I'm very confident that I passed the background check because if not then they will not send me an invite for the induction.

I hope you understand what I'm feeling since this is the first time I resigned and the onboarding process of my first job didn't took that long.

**Update 1 (April 30, 2021)**

I haven't got a response from the text I sent to their HR Coordinator so I decided to send an email today in the afternoon regarding my on-boarding status.

**Update 2 (April 30, 2021)**

Got an email response that I should kindly wait for email updates that will be sent to me with regards to my concern.

Comment: Welcome new user.  What country is this?  Also, is the new place of work physically near you, could you go there?

Comment: @Fattie Hi, I'm from the Philippines. Because of the pandemic the work setup will be work from home. I could go to the new work place using my motorcycle, it would take 1 hour max with heavy traffic to go there. The whole hiring process were done digitally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Any update for us :)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They gave you a contract to sign. That is as much certainty as anyone can have that the job is yours. It is understandable that you are worried, but you should have faith that they are just understaffed or dealing with other more pressing tasks, and that is why you have not heard back from them yet.

That said, if you have not heard by lunchtime on Friday (since you're due to start Monday), I would email or actually call them to check that everything is OK.

One way to stop yourself worrying too much: if they have withdrawn the offer, then nothing you can do or say now will affect that outcome. If that is the case then you will probably be asking for your old job back on Monday, so mentally preparing yourself for that may also help you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I already sent an email to know the status of my on-boarding. Hoping for a positive response from them.